# Необходимо перевести этот код на Java

Tags: java

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long  n, k;
    long double length, width;
    cin >> n;
    length = floor(sqrt(n));
    width = ceil(n/length);
    k = 2*n + length + width;
    cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот сайт — не бюро переводов

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну я перевел. Я даже Java не знаю, все гуглил XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long long  n, k;
        long double length, width;
        n = in.nextInt();
        length = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
        width = Math.ceil(n/length);
        k = 2*n + length + width;
        System.out.print(k + "/n");
    }
}
```

Comment: long long  n, k; это не совсем корректно, но спасибо

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин ну я джаву вобще не знаю), вы уж поправьте)

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин примете?

Comment: Слушайте, ну я все понимаю, но зачем голосовать против на ответ, который старались, писали?

Comment: Странные люди...@Ver Nick спасибо, помог

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин да уж...

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин примете?

Comment: что значит принять?)

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин зелененькая галочка рядом с ответом. кликните на нее, вам 2 балла репутации, мне 15 )

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин Спасибо)

Comment: да нажал, первый мой вопрос просто, не знал нюансов)

Comment: @ИгорьМетлин Вы только таких вопросов лучше не задавайте, будут минусить)

Comment: я уже понял это)

Comment: Минусы потому что вопрос плохо задан ("непонятна суть вопроса", что именно непонятно автору или "домашка" мне лень самому делать), но впрочем всегда найдётся "[Подрастающая смена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7304/213987)", кто готов делать любые задания.

Comment: Привык сразу переходить к делу, а не лить воду. Врятли кому-то интересно домашка это или что-то другое.